# Why result Q is X?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog, xilinx, hdl

- I'm using Xilinx 14.7 for test simulation.
- This code is custom from My Japanese Verilog Book.

**Verilog Code**

```
module Q41(clk,q1,reset,q2);
        input clk,reset;
        output  [7:0] q1,q2;
        reg     [7:0] q1,q2;
        reg     a;
        always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
        begin
            if(reset)
                begin
                a  <= 0 ;
                q1 <= 8'h0; 
                q2 <= 8'h0; 
                end 
            else if(a<=0)
                begin                       
                    if(q1>=8'h14)   
                        begin   q1  <= 8'h14;   a <= 1; end 
                    else                    
                        q1 <= q1+1;             
                end
            else  
                begin                       
                    if(q1<=8'h0)    
                        begin   q1 <= 8'h0;     a <= 0; end 
                    else                    
                        q1 <= q1-1;             
                end
            if(a<=0)
                q2 <=q2+q1;
            else
                q2 <=q2-q1;
        end
    endmodule
```

**Test Bench**

```
    `timescale 1ps/1ps
    module Q41TestBench;
        reg clk;
        reg reset;
        wire [7:0] q1;
        wire [7:0] q2;
        parameter step = 10000; // 10ns
        Q41 uut (clk, q1, reset, q2);
        always begin
            clk = 0; #(step/2);
            clk = 1;    #(step/2);
        end
        initial begin
                reset = 1;
        #step reset = 0;
        #step clk   = 0;
        #(step*100) $finish;
        end
        initial $monitor($stime,
        " clk = %d reset = %d Q = %d",clk,reset,q2);
    endmodule
```

**Result**

view result image

[image: Please click here for view result image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have placed Q2 in two separate constructs.  You have Q2 reset in your traditional IF(reset) and then you have a separate IF managing the assignment of Q2.  I'll recommend the following recode where q2 is in the same IF construct.

```
if(reset)
    begin
       a  <= 0 ;
       q1 <= 8'h0; 
       q2 <= 8'h0; 
    end 
else if(a<=0) 
    begin 
       q2 <= q2+q1                      
       if(q1>=8'h14)   
           begin   
           q1 <= 8'h14;  
           a  <= 1; 
           end 
       else
           begin                 
           q1 <= q1+1;
           a <= a; // I like to make sure that everything is always assigned   
           end          
    end
else  
    begin 
       q2 <=q2-q1;                      
       if(q1<=8'h0)    
          begin   
          q1 <= 8'h0;     
          a <= 0; 
          end 
       else
          begin                    
          q1 <= q1-1;
          a <= a;
          end             
    end
```

Comment: Just to add one more rational, in your original code, If the module is in reset, the q2 <= 8'h0 because of the reset clause, and the gets assigned as  q2 <=q2-q1;  with non-blocking assignment.  In other words, the simulator attempts to assign both at the same time.  The result is undefined.